# Why won't alert work inside of host function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this curious thing happening. When I place the alert function inside the addition function, nothing happens. And the console is not showing any error mesages.

When I place the alert function outside the addition function I get the message with the total variable's declared value of zero. What am I not getting about this process.?

```
var w = 3;
var x = 4;
var y = 5;
var z = 6;
var total = 0;
function addition (w,x,y,z){
    return(w,x,y,z)

    total=(w+x+y+z);

    alert(total);
}
```

Comment: Functions do not proceed to execute after a `return` statement. The `alert()` is considered to be unreachable code being after `return(w,x,y,z)`. – Also, it doesn't appear that `addition()` is being called yet.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan Lonowski, that clears up my confusion. And, it gives me great info for the future. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

A function immediately ends once `return` is called. You need to put your alerts before it.

Comment: Thank you, Michael Stroud. Great info to keep in mind.